# missing connection string on deploy

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I built a prototype I'm looking to deploy. It uses a database file MySite.mdf that I created. At some point in the process, the database file ASPNETDB.mdf was added to the project.

When I look at the web.config file, I see the connectionStrings tag but in there I only see the nested tag for MySite.

Now that I'm looking to deploy, what do I put for the second file in the  tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a [SQL Server Express User Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx); if the server you are deploying to support this, then you won't need to change your connection string when you deploy.

The most common problem deploying a user instance database is that the server doesn't support user instances. (Note that user instances are only supported by SQL Server Express Edition). If the server doesn't support this configuration, you'll have to create a database on the server and change your connection string, a process that could involve quite a few steps.

If, on the other hand, your server supports users instances and it's using the same SQL Instance name that you are, e.g. SQLEXPRESS, the default instance name, you should be able to simply deploy your site and it will run (as long as you include the ASPNETDB.mdf file in the deployment).